# Getting error while creating android live wallpaper - "Wallpaperservice cannot be resolved a type"

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am developing live wallpaper for android.

I am getting error "Wallpaperservice cannot be resolved a type", so it seems like I need to import some package for the same.

I imported package android.app.Service package, but eclipse is showing that package is not available.

So, do I need to download this package manually or anything else.
Please guide.

Comment: It might help if you posted some code that we could take a look at.

Comment: I am using same code as given in the tutorial,
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/src/com/example/android/livecubes/cube1/CubeWallpaper1.html

Comment: And your API level is 7?  Min SDK is 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
```

But maybe your problem is your build target?  You need to specify API 7 (Android 2.1) or higher.

Comment: Yes, It was problem with build target in manifest file, Solved now.
Thank you very much to everyone for help !!